# How does numpy.fft.fft work?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am currently trying to understand the fft-function from numpy. For that I tested the following assumption:
I have two functions, `f(x) = x^2` and `g(x) = f'(x) = 2*x`. According to the fourier transformation laws and wolfram alpha it should be that `G(w) = 2pi*i*F(w)` (prefactors can vary, but there should only be a constant factor). When implementing that in python, I write

```
import numpy as np
def x2(x):
    return x*x
def nx(x):
    return 2*x

a = np.linspace(-3, 3, 16)
a1 = x2(a)
a2 = nx(a)

b1 = np.fft.fft(a1)
b2 = np.fft.fft(a2)

c = b1/b2
```

Now I am expecting a nearly constant value for `c`, but I get

```
array([  1.02081592e+16+0.j        ,   1.32769987e-16-1.0054679j ,
         4.90653893e-17-0.48284271j,  -1.28214041e-16-0.29932115j,
        -1.21430643e-16-0.2j       ,   5.63664751e-16-0.13363573j,
        -5.92271642e-17-0.08284271j,  -4.21346622e-16-0.03978247j,
        -5.55111512e-16-0.j        ,  -5.04781597e-16+0.03978247j,
        -6.29288619e-17+0.08284271j,   8.39500693e-16+0.13363573j,
        -1.21430643e-16+0.2j       ,  -0.00000000e+00+0.29932115j,
        -0.00000000e+00+0.48284271j,   1.32769987e-16+1.0054679j ])
```

Where is my mistake, and what can I do to use the fft as intended?

Comment: The incorrect part here is `G(w) = 2 pi i F(w)`.  Should be `G(w) = 2 pi i w F(w)`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: What is w in those arrays, and is it also imaginary?

Comment: @arc_lupus `w` is the frequency-space equivalent to `x`.  In this case, you have `x^2` in the original space, which has no frequency, per se (at least not in the easy-to-understand sense), so you will get a multitude of different peaks to represent `x^2`.  E.g., if `f(x) = sin(x)`, then you would have a nice, simple delta func at 1 to capture the simple frequency in `sin(x)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The properties you give apply to the [*Continuous* Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) (CFT). What is computed by the FFT is the [*Discrete* Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT), which is related to the CFT but is not exactly equivalent.

It's true that the DFT is proportional to the CFT under certain conditions: namely with sufficient sampling of a function that is zero outside the sample limits (see e.g. Appendix E of [this book](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10159.html)).

Neither condition holds for the functions you propose above, so the DFT is not proportional to the CFT and your numerical results reflect that.

---

Here's some code that confirms via the FFT the relationship you're interested in, using an appropriately sampled band-limited function:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.exp(-x ** 2)
def fprime(x):
    return -2 * x * f(x)

a = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
a1 = f(a)
a2 = fprime(a)

b1 = np.fft.fft(a1)
b2 = np.fft.fft(a2)
omega = 2 * np.pi * np.fft.fftfreq(len(a), a[1] - a[0])

np.allclose(b1 * 1j * omega, b2)
# True
```